# How to process duplicates in scrapy?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I'm learning scrapy and I have some small project.

```
def parse(self, response):
    links = LinkExtractor().extract_links(response)
    for link in links:
            yield response.follow(link, self.parse)

    if (some_condition):
        yield {'url': response.url}  # Store some data
```

So I open a page get all links form it and store some data if I have some data on this page. And for example, if I processed `http://example.com/some_page` then it will skip it next time. And my task is to process it even next time. I want to know that this page has been already processed and I need to store some other data in this case. It should be something like:

```
def parse(self, response):

    if (is_duplicate):
        yield{} # Store some other data
    else:
        links = LinkExtractor().extract_links(response)
        for link in links:
                yield response.follow(link, self.parse)

        if (some_condition):
            yield {'url': response.url}  # Store some data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to track links you visit and second, you have to tell Scrapy you want to visit same pages repeatedly.

Change the code this way:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.visited_links = set()

def parse(self, response):
    if response.url in self.visited_links:
        yield {} # Store some other data
    else:
        self.visited_links.add(response.url)

        links = LinkExtractor().extract_links(response)
        for link in links:
            yield response.follow(link, self.parse, dont_filter=True)

        if (some_condition):
            yield {'url': response.url}  # Store some data
```

In constructor added, `visited_links` is used to keep track of links you already visisted. (Here I suppose you spider class is named `MySpider`, you didn't share this part of code.) In `parse`, you first check if link is already visited (URL is in the `visited_links` set). If not, you add it to visited links set and when yielding new `Request` (using `response.follow`), you instruct Scrapy not to filter duplicate request using `dont_filter=True`.

Comment: That's work but it looks like if I do like this it will crawl external links too. So I should filter them myself?

Comment: `dont_filter` influences just filtering duplicate requests.

Comment: @GhostKU `links = LinkExtractor(allow_domains=self.allowed_domains).extract_links(response)`